# How to override VSCode Intellisense inference with JSDoc comment

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, ramda.js, javascript-intellisense

VSCode's Intellisense ignores my JSDoc comment and instead is inferring what the definition should be.

Function with JSDoc comment:

```
/**
 * @param { Array<number> } arrayOfNumbers
 * @return { number } sum - the sum of the arrayOfNumbers
 */
const getSumOfArrayElements = reduce (add, 0)
```

VSCode output:

```
const getSumOfArrayElements: (list: readonly any[]) => number
@param arrayOfNumbers

@return — sum - the sum of the arrayOfNumbers
```

Intellisense is defining `getSumOfArrayElements` as the definition for the return value of `reduce (add, 0)` (`reduce` with 2 arguments supplied)

Is there a way to have JSDoc comments have top priority in VSCode?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just noting that this does work as expected

```
/**
 * @param { Array<number> } arrayOfNumbers
 * @return { number } sum - the sum of the arrayOfNumbers
 */
const getSumOfArrayElements = arrayOfNumbers => reduce (add, 0) (arrayOfNumbers)
```

Also, adding `@function` to the JSDoc comment doesn't change anything.

Comment: JSDoc does not use `<>` AFAIK

Comment: VSCode does show other definitions with `<>`, I'm not sure if there's some nuanced difference between the two formats though. But switching to `@param { number[] } arrayOfNumbers` doesn't change the VSCode output.

Comment: And how does the signature of the `reduce` function look?

Comment: The reduce signature is this: `((a, b) → a) → a → [b] → a`. VSCode shows this ```function reduce<T, TResult>(fn: (acc: TResult, elem: T) => TResult | Reduced<TResult>, acc: TResult, list: readonly T[]): TResult (+2 overloads)```

Comment: The JSDoc signature for Ramda is available [in the source](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/698bdc4efa56dae0f41b6529b860c3a6ed02a0ec/source/reduce.js#L36-L40).  But it looks as though you're seeing the TS signatures [from DefinitivelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/71ec22215e040ef6a0ac971dae59accb6f568287/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L1831-L18333).  How to make it show something else, I don't know.